# Gridview with multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

Using C# and ASP.NET, I need my gridview to draw columns from multiple tables. How do I do this? I currently have

```
`SelectCommand="SELECT [SubId], [CustName], [CustCity] FROM [Customer]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

as my select statement, but I need to select from two more tables. What is the syntax?

*apologies for being unclear before.*

Comment: You mean grab data from multiple tables in the DB?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the muddled question. Would something like 
`SELECT [SubId],[CustName] FROM [Customer] AND [BroName] FROM [Broker] AND [Entity] FROM [Submission]`
work?

Comment: No - you would need something like `Select SubId, CustName, BroName, Entity from Customer inner join Broker on BrokerCustomerIdField=CustomerId inner join Submission on SubmissionCustomerId=CustomerId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SelectCommand should be the same statement that you would execute if you were running the query on the database directly. So, in your case, you would want something like:

```
SELECT [SubId], [CustName], [BroName], [Entity] 
FROM [Customer] 
JOIN [Broker] ON <join condition> 
JOIN [Submission] ON <join condition>
```

Comment: Thanks, @esteuart. It looked like this when I was done: 
`SELECT Customer.SubId, Customer.CustName, Customer.CustCity, Customer.CustState, Broker.BroName, Broker.BroState, Broker.EntityType, Submission.Coverage, Submission.Status FROM Customer INNER JOIN Broker ON Customer.SubId = Customer.SubId INNER JOIN Submission ON Submission.SubmissionId = Customer.SubId`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to update the SqlDataSource, you can simply put JOINS into your query.

For example:-

`Select CustFld1, CustFld2, OrdFld1, OrdFld2 from Cust inner join Ord on CustPKeyFld=OrdCustFKeyField`

If you do need to update the SqlDataSource, you need to use sub-queries to return the data that would otherwise be returned in the join

For example:-

`Select CustFld1, CustFld2, (Select OrdFld1 from Ord where OrdCustFkeyFld=CustPKeyFld) as OrdFld1, (Select OrdFld2 from Ord where OrdCustFKeyFld=CustPKeyFld) as OrdFld2 from Cust`